# Transfer all environment variables from one shell to another automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh, zsh

I want to transfer all environment variables of the one shell (in my case: kornshell) to another shell (in my case: the z-shell) automatically.

If possible, the transfer should be in the startup file of the zshell to aviod the use of additional scripts as I want to transfer it to other servers for the same purpose.

What I tried so far:

1. put `$ export $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ')` in the .zshrc (Startupfile of the Zshell).

   This was not working because the command is executed as a child of the current shell     (zsh) which consequently has the same environment variables as the zsh and NOT the environment of the kornshell.
2. in an extra script

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ksh
   echo $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ') # for testing if it works
   export $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ')
   ```

   This doent's work either.

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Indent and numbered lists don't play together nicely. Try numbering with `1)` etc.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, they do. Whatever should be inside a list needs to be indented by 4 + whatever it would otherwise need spaces. That is 8 for verbatim.

Comment: Can you describe the use-case in more detail? For one thing transferring *all* environment variables will probably screw things up hard (some are shell-specific), for another the ones you are probably interested in are not made up by the shell, but rather read from somewhere, so just making sure the other shell picks them up there is probably easier option. But more details are needed to tell for sure.

Comment: I'm working on a server where the standard shell is the korn shell.  If some of the variables should change, administrators will only change those in the ksh. That's why I wanted to automatically read them on startup of the zsh. If you want to use another shell (can't change the kshell config as I'm not the only one using it), you need to transfer those env variables somehow to the other shell. The .profile file of the korn shell does not include all env variables I need (f.e. DISPLAY, some SSH_CLIENT definition, ...) and I don't know how to find them. Thought it was easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your `ksh` in an empty environment:

```
export $(env -i ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
export $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ')
```

does not work for me because "env" returns text like:

```
key1=value1 value2
...
```

So the above command will expand $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ') and run:

```
export key1=value1 value2
```

But this generates error:

```
export: value2: is not an identifier
```

Note that there may be other bad characters on the right side of "=" sign in the output of "env", which will produce errors.

But there is a better way to export environment:

```
 export -p > myenv.sh
```

this outputs in Bash

```
 declare -x key1="value1 value2"
 ....
```

It appears that Bash "declare -x" is the same as "export".
But in ksh "export -p" prints

```
export key1='value1 value2'
...
```

Now I just need to run

```
source myenv.sh
```

to export all variables

But I also need to delete all existing variables before exporting new.
I found solution at:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-unset-environment-variable-in-bash-383066/

So, my final code is:

```
unset `env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}' | xargs`
source myenv.sh
```

Comment: export $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ')
did put out
export key1=value1
export key2=value2
So that was not the problem in my case. But glad you solved yours too:)

Comment: @Cassandra: You wrote: "export key1=value1 export key2=value2", but what if value of key1 contains a space or other special characters? What does "export $(ksh -c env | tr '\n' ' ')" prints in this case in your environment?

Comment: Hey jhnlmn, no special characters present in my case. It looked like described above: 
export key1=value1
export key2=value2
My problem was solved by unsetting the environment first (as you did too).

Answer (score 1):

How about using . /path/to/your/shell/script.sh to run your script.
You can run a shell script by three different means, 
1) `/bin/sh /path/to/your/shell/script.sh`
2) `/path/to/your/shell/script.sh`
3) `. /path/to/your/shell/script.sh`
You can check it out.

Comment: Hey George. 
 not sure how can that help with the environment problem. I tried all of those already, although I'm not sure about the conceptual difference. It didn't make any difference. Did you try in your shell if the env. variables are those of the other shell?

The problem is the parent process, the shell, that passes its env variables down to any child process, no matter how invoked (?).

Comment: source, . (dot command)

    This command, when invoked from the command-line, executes a script. Within a script, a source file-name loads the file file-name. Sourcing a file (dot-command) imports code into the script, appending to the script (same effect as the #include directive in a C program). The net result is the same as if the "sourced" lines of code were physically present in the body of the script. This is useful in situations when multiple scripts use a common data file or function library.  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#BUILTINREF

Comment: ah, interesting, thank you. On the command line, I used ./myscript.sh und . or source myscript.sh as synonyms so far.